# How to set that compiler flag?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, shark

Shark told me this:

> This instruction is the start of a
>   loop that is not aligned to a 16-byte
>   address boundary. For optimal
>   performance, you should align the
>   start of a hot loop using a compiler
>   directive. With gcc 3.3 or later, use
>   the -falign-loops=16 compiler flag.

```
for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) { // line with the info
   //...code
}
```

How would I set that flag, and does it really improve performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hints from Shark are not always appropriate. Aligning loops doesn't make a lot of difference in most cases. Focus on the bottlenecks in your code and see what you can do at the algo/code level before resorting to very minor tweaks such as this.